# LiVES hangs during initial configuration

Tags: 12.04, installation, configuration, video-editor

I'd like to install the Video Editing Software LiVES on my Ubuntu 12.04. The installation itself worked without any problems. When I now start LiVES it runs through the initial configuration until the Dialog **LiVES: -Testing Configuration** appears, which shows 4 tests being executed (all of them successfully, with a green check). Problem is, the Next-Button is disabled, so I can't continue with the configuration. When trying to use the Cancel-Button, the application seems to hang and I have to kill the process.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated. While answering this question, please keep in mind, that I'm relatively new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

What version of LiVES are you using ? This may be related to a bug which was fixed in version 1.6.3. (LiVES hangs on install if pulseaudio is not installed).

A workaround is to install pulseaudio before running LiVES for the first time. You can then remove pulseaudio after the LiVES configuration process.